# How to wait until all commands are executed and only then have a prompt to restart your PC in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script for enabling some Windows Features. It looks like something like this:

```
...
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-WebServerRole"
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-WebServer"
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "IIS-FTPServer"
...
```

In this script, there are multiple commands where I enable Windows features which require a restart. I noticed that in PowerShell, it's enabling stuff, and then the last 4 lines where I enable stuff that requires restart, it's constantly prompting me to restart the computer in powershell. So I have to constantly say "No" because otherwise it'll restart the computer before all the commands in the script are executed:

[image]

In my script, how do I wait until all commands are executed, and only then have a prompt about restarting my PC? I tried adding "Wait-Process" and "-Wait" tags to the commands, but I got errors like this:
[image]

Does anyone know a way I could wait for all the commands to execute and only then have a restart prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` has a `-NoRestart` switch. [Described as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

> Suppresses reboot. If a reboot is not required, this command does
> nothing. This option will keep the application from prompting for a
> restart or keep it from restarting automatically.

Answer (score 2):

To build on [@zdan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72176986/584676), use the `-NoRestart` flag. You could either omit `-NoRestart` to the final feature, or do the prompt yourself which leaves you open to alternative logic patterns to install a list of desired features:

```
'IIS-WebServerRole', 'IIS-WebServer', 'IIS-FTPServer' | ForEach-Object {
  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $_ -NoRestart
}

if( ( Read-Host -Prompt "Would you like to reboot to complete feature installation? (y/n)" ) -match '^y' ) {
  Restart-Computer -Force
}
```

Or if you want to keep it simple and don't need custom prompt text before prompting for the reboot, simply use the `-Confirm` switch with `Restart-Computer` in order to get a reboot prompt:

```
'IIS-WebServerRole', 'IIS-WebServer', 'IIS-FTPServer' | ForEach-Object {
  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $_ -NoRestart
}

Restart-Computer -Confirm -Force
```